# Почему куки не самоуничтожаются?

Tags: php, cookie

По умолчанию  cookie уничтожаются при закрытии окна браузера. Почему тогда если я установлю какую-либо куки переменную, закрою окно браузера и снова открою (даже и на следующий день ), эта(-тот) куки останется целым и невредимым?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если не указано время жизни куков то они уничтожаются не при закрытии окна браузера а **после закрытия сесси**.

Сейчас большинство браузеров поддерживает режим восстановления сессии(обычно это в настройках по умолчанию. По крайней мере в Firefox точно). Так что сессия на самом деле не прерывается соответственно куки и не уничтожаются.

Comment: Литературу всю - в доменную печь! Зачем вводят в заблуждение? Ведь всюду черным по белому написано "ВРЕМЯ ЖИЗНИ КУКИ - ДО ОКОНЧАНИЯ РАБОТЫ ОКНА БРАУЗЕРА". Еще,например, Кузнецов широко практикует указание ключей массива без кавычек ($_POST[key]) и т.д. и т.п.  Куда мир катится?

Comment: @Deus, возможно во время написания книги браузеры не умели восстанавливать сессию и поэтому фраза "ВРЕМЯ ЖИЗНИ КУКИ - ДО ОКОНЧАНИЯ РАБОТЫ ОКНА БРАУЗЕРА" звучит абсолютно верно. Возможно можно как-то объяснить и указание ключей массива без кавычек в php. :)

Comment: отключение `NOTICE` в пхп) и до кучи включение `register_globals = on` :)))

Comment: И вообще, туда же и в том же духе